# How can you change a rootweb name, url etc?

Tags: 2010, powershell, spweb, spsite

How can I change the name on a root web?

Right now it's `http://dev1/sites/dog`.

I am trying to change it to `http://dev1/sites/cat`

I have tried

```
$web = get-spweb http://dev1/sites/dog
$web.Name = "cat"
$web.Update()
```

But I get an exception that its not possible to move the root web?

I have also tried to do it via `SPSite.Rename()` and `.Rootweb.Name`.

I couldn't find any answers at all beside some guy that said it's only possible with sub webs.

Comment: you can change the "Title". what you apparently want is to change the URL

Comment: http://www.sharepointrelated.com/2015/03/30/change-site-collection-url-sharepoint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to change the url of the site collections, but only 1 is fool proof and recomended by MSFT.

**Recommended**

- Use the Backup-Spsite to perform the backup of site collection
- Use Restore-spsite to peform the restore spsite.
- Lastly remove-spsiste to remove old site collection.

**example**

```
Backup-SPSite http://dev1/sites/dog –Path C:\Backup\DBackup.bak 

Restore-SPSite http://dev1/sites/Cat –Path E:\Backup\HRBackup.bak

Remove-SPSite http://dev1/sites/dog –GradualDelete
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/erica/2013/11/26/customer-question-renaming-site-collections-in-sharepoint-2013/

Other Methods are

- Use copy-spsite but its not worked all the time and has limitation.
- or using the Spsite.Rename funcation, not worked all the time. In many cases you have to do extra work, fix the broken webparts,refresh the configuration and most important perform IIS reset.

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=573

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://dev1/sites/dog

$site.Rename("http://dev1/sites/cat")
```

Additional information:
http://www.sharepointrelated.com/2015/03/30/change-site-collection-url-sharepoint/

Notice the catch pointed in the article (but in your case should work):

> There is a little catch to this. You can only use this to rename site
>   collection URL’s that – Use “Wildcard inclusion” Managed Paths. – Are
>   Host named site collections (In which case you could also use
>   Set-SPSiteURL)
>
> You can’t use it to change http://sharepoint/sites/marketing to
>   http://sharepoint/marketing (Even if the Explicit inclusion managed
>   path exists).